# Visual Studio: How to check, notify (and push) users to the latest version

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, auto-update, notify

I looked around on the internet, but I can't seem to find a good and easy way to check the version of the application. To then notify the user if their application is outdated, and then to update the application to the latest version.

In my set up, 20 people have the same application running on their pc, but when I create an update, I now have to send them an email with the request to update to the latest version.  I now want to let this be done automatically.

---

Since I can't find anything, I was thinking of storing the latest version in a txt file, and let the application check this file every day to its own version.  If there is a difference, then I would let them download the latest executable.  From that moment however they should launch the update themselves.

Is there an easier or better way to do this?

Thanks, and also my best wishes for the new year.

Gert

Comment: One of the most simple ways is, as you say, to let it check a .txt file on your website/DropBox/etc. and compare that to the application's current version. This guy's got a pretty good example: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BXob1nqpAI0

Comment: Thanks! If nobody else has another/better way, then I'll continue working like this.

Comment: I wrote a loader program and have the users run the loader instead of the application. The loader checks the create time on the local and LAN versions of the file and offers to do the update (it also downloads the latest settings file for the initial load of the loader and the application.) During the offer I also display a change log in an expanded dialog so the users can see what is new. It can also do other things like allow the user to load a test DB versions instead of the production DB. The loaded application performs the same service for the loader - updating it if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx)  deployment. There is a way to force users to update by specifying a [minimum version number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e(v=vs.90).aspx). This method works well in an enterprise environment.

Answer (score 1):

Also look into [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) as a ClickOnce replacement for autoupdating

Comment: Thanks both for your answer.
I now used the text file option, but on my next project I'm going to use this.